# LAZY LOADING "NAMESPACE" COMPONENT IN REACTJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm try to write a **namespace component** in ReactJS. It has some problem that when i import a component "**Menu**" as **lazy loading** ( Menu already contain a component "**Item**" ) => when i used "**Menu.Item**" typescript will ping an error that "**"Item" not exist in LazyExoticComponent<{}>**". Anyone can help me please :(

Here is an example of me on codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-estrela-y63hyp?file=/src/App.tsx

***Menu.tsx

```
const MenuItem = ({ name }: { name: string }) => {
  return <p>{name}</p>;
};
const Menu = ({ children }: any) => {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
};
Menu.Item = MenuItem;
export default Menu;
```

***App.tsx

```
import { lazy } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
// good
// import Menu from "./components/menu";
// not good
const Menu = lazy(() => import("./components/menu"));
// Menu.Item not working when using lazy load...
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Menu>
        this is error is below
        <Menu.Item name="element 1" />
        <Menu.Item name="element 2" />
        <Menu.Item name="element 3" />
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you post code in the question itself instead of a link?

Comment: Please don't YELL AT US in your title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to separate the menu and menuItem scripts, with the Lazy you can't export several components you have to do it one by one, you can't apply destructuring. If you want to have everything in one file and apply shredding you need to implement a library --> https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazily

now for now this work:

```
import { lazy } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
// good
// import Menu from "./components/menu";
// not good
const Menu = lazy(() => import("./components/menu"));
const MenuItem = lazy(() => import("./components/menuItem"));
// Menu.Item not working when using lazy load...
console.log(Menu);
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Menu>
        <MenuItem name="element 1" />
        <MenuItem name="element 2" />
        <MenuItem name="element 3" />
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
}
```

menu:

```
const Menu = ({ children }: any) => {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
};

export default Menu;
```

menuitem

```
const MenuItem = ({ name }: { name: string }) => {
  return <p>{name}</p>;
};
export default MenuItem;
```

Comment: it work.. tks you.. maybe "namespace component" dont' work well with lazy loading